# Como puedo eliminar una Tabla en SQLite con Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

tengo este código, que según yo debería eliminar una tabla que se creo en una base de datos SQLite con Swift, pero cuando ejecuto la función no se elimina, la primera función es la de la creación y la que abre la conexión a la base de datos, de ahi esta la función de eliminar tabla que es la que no me esta funcionando.

```
init()
    {
        db = openDatabase()
        
    }

    let dbPath: String = "DataBase.sqlite"
    var db:OpaquePointer?
    
    
    
    
        //Creo la BD y abro la conexión

    func openDatabase() -> OpaquePointer?
    {
        let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent(dbPath)
        var db: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK
        {
            print("Error al abrir la Base de Datos")
            return nil
        }
        else
        {
            print("Se ha creado y abierto la BD: \(dbPath)")
            return db
        }
                
    }

func eliminarTabla(tabla: String){
        
        let dropStatementString = "DROP TABLE 'DataBase.\(tabla)';"
        var dropStatement : OpaquePointer? = nil
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, dropStatementString, -1, &dropStatement, nil)
        if sqlite3_step(dropStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
            print("Se ha eliminado la tabla \(tabla)")
        } else {
            print("No se pudo eliminar la tabla.")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(dropStatement)
    }
```

Me podrían decir donde esta el error.
Gracias

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En tu código falta que abras la conexión a la base de datos y en el `prepare` estás utilizando `db` y no el `OpaquePointer` que abre la conexión a la base.

```
func eliminarTabla(tabla: String){
    
    let dropStatementString = "DROP TABLE 'DataBase.\(tabla)';"
    var dropStatement : OpaquePointer? = nil
    //Abrir base de datos
    if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &dropStatement) != SQLITE_OK {
        print("error opening database")
    }
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(dropStatement, dropStatementString, -1, &dropStatement, nil)//Cambias el db por dropStatement en la cual abriste la base de datos
    if sqlite3_step(dropStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
        print("Se ha eliminado la tabla \(tabla)")
    } else {
        print("No se pudo eliminar la tabla.")
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(dropStatement)
}
```

Comment: acabo de acompletar la funcion que hace la conexión y de ahi la variable db, pero no se por que no me borra, Gracias!

Comment: En el prepare estás usando `dropStatement` que es `nil` y debería ser `&db`. Además puedes agregar `sqlite3_errmsg(db)` para que veas qué error tienes.